# Automating JBoss deployment in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss

I'm looking for a way to automate deployment of a Flex application(written in Eclipse) EAR to the JBoss application server. That is, when I click 'Build' I want it to also do the deployment. It doesn't have to be a 'hot' deployment, since this is development I don't care about shutting down and restarting the application.

Answer (score 4):

[JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) has kept me happy for a few months now. It was a bit tricky to get it up and running, but it's a real time saver once you've nailed the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the jboss server to auto deploy.

double click on the JBoss server in the server view, then select Publishing -> and click the Automatically public when resources change, set the interval to quite low.

Btw, you might want to look for the Jboss plugin - it works very well and makes deployment much faster.